# Selecting rows from array under many conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to extract rows from a large numpy array.  The columns of the array are obs number, group id (j), time id (t), and some data x_jt.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
N = 100
T = 100
X = np.vstack((np.array(range(1,N*T+1)),np.repeat(np.array(range(1,N+1)),T), np.tile(np.array(range(1,T+1)),N), np.random.randint(100,size=N*T))).T
```

If I want to extract all rows from X where group id = 2, I would do

```
X[np.where(X[:,1] == 2)]
```

And if I wanted all rows where j = 2 or 3, I could extend that code.  However, in my case, I have many group ids (j's) to extract.  Specifically, I want to extract all rows where j comes from

```
samples = np.random.randint(N, size=N) + 1
```

For example, suppose size = 5 instead of N, and samples = (2,4,5,4,7).  What I am after is code that goes through X and selects all rows where j = 2, then j = 4, then j = 5, j = 4, and finally j = 7, and creates a new array with the results.  Basically this:

```
result = []
for j in samples:
    result.extend(X[np.where(X[:,1] == j)])
```

However, this code is slow when N is large.  Do you have any suggestions to speed it up?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Without replacement

This could be done with vectorized functions:

```
def contains(X, samples):
    return numpy.vectorize(lambda x: x in samples)(X)

result = X[contains(X[:, 1], set(samples)), :]
```

## With replacement

If you want to do this with replacement just check off one count per sample until there are no more samples (assuming the order does not matter). This way you at least reduce the amount of times you need to iterate over the matrix.

```
result = []
sample_counts = collections.Counter(samples)
while sum(sample_counts.itervalues()):
    # pick up one of each of the remaining samples and chain their rows
    # together in result
    s = set(key for key, value in sample_counts.iteritems() if value)
    result = itertools.chain(result, X[contains(X[:, 1], s), :])
    sample_counts -= collections.Counter(dict.fromkeys(s, 1))
# create a matrix of the final result
result = numpy.array(list(result))
```

In that case the only way I can think of that might speed up what you're already doing is preallocating a matrix. So you would do:

Comment: This also does not work if samples contains repeated values (I am sampling with replacement).  Any tips?

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer for handling replacement. Haven't tested it but hopefully something like that should work.    I'm not sure if my vectorized contains function is faster than the in1d function suggested by Jaime. If the in1d function searches through the entire list each time than I'm guessing my contains function is faster since you're using sets in there.

Comment: Tested it and it seems to work (didn't really hunt for edge cases though).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't do exactly what you are describing, but this type of problems are a good candidate for [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html). Something like this should work:

```
result = X[np.in1d(X[:, 1], samples)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the lead.  You're right, this isn't exactly what I need because it only extracts set(samples) of X, instead of possible repeated values of j within samples, i.e. when samples = (4,5,4).